# How can I get a Scrapy spider to run with multiple pipelines?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy project that pulls data from a site and upload that data to multiple tables in a PostreSQL database. The below is a simplified version of my code:

My pipelines.py file:

```
class PoliticiansPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider): #opens the database connection
    def close_spider(self, spider): #closes the database connection
    def process_item(self, item, spider): #pulls data from item and uploads it to database

class HouseMembersPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider): #opens the database connection
    def close_spider(self, spider): #closes the database connection
    def process_item(self, item, spider): #pulls data from item and uploads it to database
```

And from my settings.py file:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'house_members.pipelines.PoliticiansPipeline': 100,
    'house_members.pipelines.HouseMembersPipeline': 200,
}
```

But every time that I run the script in the command line, it returns the error `"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"`. I have run each pipeline separately and they work with no error. I have also combined both pipelines into one large pipeline and it also works. But when I separate it out into multiple pipelines, it stops working.

I haven't been able to find any true examples showing this and the Scrapy documentation didn't explicitly detail out how to handle multiple pipelines. Does anyone have examples of their pipeline working or a resource I can use to troubleshoot? Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Below is the stack trace of the error:

```
2018-06-26 23:27:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] 
ERROR: Error processing {'first_name': 'Mike', 'last_name': 'Gallagher', 'party': 'R', 'state': 'WI', 'district': '8th'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\cmatt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
  current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "C:\Users\cmatt\eclipse-workspace\house_members\house_members\pipelines.py", line 92, in process_item
  new_tuple = (item['first_name'], item['last_name'], item['party'], item['state'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please provide complete stack trace

Comment: @TarunLalwani Okay the stack trace of the error has been added.

Comment: Can you print the `item` before the line where error is happening? Also in your pipeline are you returning the item or not? May be you are not and next pipeline is getting it as `None`

Comment: @TarunLalwani that actually resolved it. The issue was stemming from a check in the first pipeline. If the item was already in the database, the script was told to "pass". When I changed it to "return item", and still without uploading it, it worked perfectly. Is this a key step in building out multiple pipelines is to return the item as the last step of the pipeline?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Also, I very much appreciate the help with this process. Spent way too long debugging this.

Answer (score 3):

When you define your pipelines like below

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'house_members.pipelines.PoliticiansPipeline': 100,
    'house_members.pipelines.HouseMembersPipeline': 200,
}
```

`PoliticiansPipeline` will be called first and `HouseMembersPipeline` later. The first pipeline can modify the item and return it, or it can drop the item all together. To drop you can do

```
raise DropItem("Item already in DB")
```

Doing this, will make sure the later pipelines are not called. But if you return the item, then the returned item is given to the next pipeline. In your case since you didn't return anything in first pipeline the next pipeline got `None` in the `item` parameter and hence the error. So make sure you return the item in every pipeline

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation. This is something that is not stated well at all in the Scrapy documentation. Appreciate the help!